# PHP: Add difference from two DateTime object to another date using DateTime::modify

Tags: php, datetime, date, time

How do I add the difference between two DateTime objects to another DateTime object? I tried some code similar to the one below, but it didn't work.

```
$first_time=new DateTime('01/01/2000 00:00:00');
$second_time=new DateTime('01/01/2000 00:00:50');
$diff=$first_time->diff($second_time);
$time=new DateTime('01/01/2012 12:00:00');
$time->modify('+'.$diff->format('%s').' seconds');
echo $time;
//Should echo: "01/01/2012 12:00:50"
```

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: What is the actual output of the echo?

Comment: If you use PHP5.3 or newer you can use DateTime::add otherwise DateTime::modify. See my answer for DateTime::modify()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`format()` does not calculate the absolut number of seconds of the Interval, it just give you the values of the intern attributes. Since you want to add, why not simply use `add()`? `diff()` returns a DateInterval object, and this is what `add()` needs.

```
$first_time=new DateTime('01/01/2000 00:00:00');
$second_time=new DateTime('01/01/2000 00:00:50');
$diff=$first_time->diff($second_time);
$time=new DateTime('01/01/2012 12:00:00');
$time->add($diff);
echo $time;
```

Comment: `DateTime::add()` is not available in PHP5.2. Thats why OP whants it with `DateTime::modify()`. See the notes [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php#refsect1-datetime.add-notes).